# "How many red counters did John put into the box?"

Tags: probability

Okay, so, my teacher gave us this worksheet of "harder/unusual probability questions", and Q.5 is real tough. I'm studying at GCSE level, so it'd be appreciated if all you stellar mathematicians explained it in a way that a 15 year old would understand. Thanks!

So, John has an empty box.
He puts some red counters and some blue counters into the box.

The ratio of the number of red counters to blue counters is 1:4

Linda takes out, at random, 2 counters from the box.

The probability that she takes out 2 red counters is 6/155

How many red counters did John put into the box?

Comment: Oh no sorry, wait

Comment: how would you have worked that out?

Comment: 25 red counters

Comment: oh, it's fine :)

Comment: damn, but how though?

Comment: cause it's one of those questions where you have to show your working out.

Comment: Do you know what ${^n}C_r$ represents?

Comment: nope. i feel so dumb, but I think I've managed to work it out using the probability of 2 red counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb in probability is that the word **and** implies multiplication, and **or** implies addition. Seeing as Linda is picking one red counter **and** one red counter, you know that its going to be the two probabilities of a red counter being picked multiplied by each other.

From here, lets call the number of red counters $r$, the number of blue counters $b$ and the total number of counters $r+b$. Given this, initially there was a $\displaystyle \frac{r}{r+b}$ chance of picking a red counter, and the next time there was a $\displaystyle \frac{r-1}{r+b-1}$ chance of picking a red counter (I'm assuming Linda has not replaced the red counter she took out initially). Given this, you can infer:

$$\frac{r}{r+b} \cdot\frac{r-1}{r+b-1}=\frac{6}{155}$$ from here, before simplifying anything, you know (for the ratio) that $\displaystyle \frac{r}{b}=\frac{1}{4}$, which is useful because it implies that $\displaystyle b=4r$, and hence the question becomes: $$\frac{r}{r+4r}\cdot\frac{r-1}{r+4r-1}=\frac{6}{155}$$ $$\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{r-1}{5r-1}=\frac{6}{155}$$  $$\frac{r-1}{25r-5}=\frac{6}{155}$$ $$155r-155=150r-30$$ $$5r=125$$ $$r=25$$

hence there are $25$ red counters in the box. I completed my GCSEs last year, and as far as I'm concerned this should all make sense to you.

P.S; which exam board are you sitting? Edexcel by any chance?

Comment: Thank you! Also, yes, I'm doing the Edexcel GCSE next year.

Comment: @Mira good luck! Stick to MSE, it's full of useful resources. :)

Comment: will do :) It's really useful, especially considering teachers at school have to explain topics to a whole class and not individually.

Comment: "I'm assuming Linda has not replaced the red counter she took out initially". You better make it:  "I'm assuming Linda took out a red counter initially and has not replaced it."

Comment: They both mean the same thing, just worded differently.

Comment: @Mira I disagree on that. It needs emphasis that the "being red" of the first counter is an assumption. In the original text it does not really come forward as an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that the first counter taken by Linda is not put back in the box.

Suppose that there are $n$ red counters in the box.

Then there are $4n$ blue counters in the box, and $5n$ counters in total.

Then the probability that the first counter taken by Linda is red is $\frac{n}{5n}=\frac15$.

*If this happens* (smells like conditional probability) then after the first shot there are $n-1$ red counters in the box and $5n-1$ counters in total.

So at her second shot the probability on a red counter is then $\frac{n-1}{5n-1}$.

That together gives a probability of $\frac15\frac{n-1}{5n-1}$ on $2$ red counters and it remains now to solve the equation:$$\frac15\frac{n-1}{5n-1}=\frac6{155}$$

Can you do that yourself?

---

If for $i=1,2$ the event that the $i$-th counter taken is red is denoted by $R_i$ then we have found the equation:$$\frac6{155}=P(R_1\cap R_2)=P(R_1)P(R_2\mid R_1)=\frac15\frac{n-1}{5n-1}$$which gives you the opportunity to find $n$.

Comment: Damn, that's complicated, but I've already managed to work out the answer, but thank you so much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

So the ratio of the number of red counters to blue is 1:4. That is, our first pull for a red has a probability of 1/5.

Let $R$ be the number of red counters. Then the probability to pull out a red after our first is $(R - 1)/(5R - 1).$ So we have $(1/5)((R - 1)/(5R - 1)) = 6/155.$ Does that make sense? I think you can work out the rest.

Comment: I needed to work out the amount of red and blue counters, not the workings behind the probability given for 2 red counters, but thanks :)

Comment: Hmm if you look closely this gives you the number of red counters.Why else would they give you the probability?

Comment: so 155/6 = 25. 83, but since that isn't an integer, I'd state it as 25. But how is that the number of red counters? I get it, but then I don't.

Comment: Oh, wait, the ratio is 1:4, which means it has 5 parts, so if I multiplied the previous answer by 4 I'd get the amount of blue counters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take number of red counters to be $x$, number of blue counters to be $4x$. Then required probability is $^{x}C_2/^{5x}C_2 = 6/155.$
$\qquad^nC_r = n!/((n-r)!r!)\quad$
Solving, we get $x(x-1)/(5x(5x-1))=6/155$, which gives $x=25.$

Comment: any way you can simplify that down, or  explain the algebra?

Answer (score 0):

John has a empty box. He puts some red counters and some blue counters. The ratio of the number of red counters to blue counters is 1:4. Linda takes at random 2 counters. The probability that she took 2 red counters is 6/155. How many red counters did John put in the box?

Let there be $x$ red counters, then there will be $4x$ blue counters which equals $5x$ counters altogether in the box.

so the probability that the first counter will be red is

Now there are $x-1$ red counters left out of $5x-1$ counters in total so

the probablility that the second counter is red is

So there were 25 red marbles in the box :)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. You seem to have left out parts of the answer? Was that intentional? Also it helps if you use MathJax.